# How to resubscribe to RACSignal after error

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I have a simple subscribeNext: error: chain like:

```
[[self.viewModel signal] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    NSLog(@"success!");
} error:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error");
}];
```

When I receive an error, I successfully print `error`, but it seems like the chain is never called again, even if the signal is sent from the view model again after the error.  I can't seem to figure out how to use `-retry` or `-repeat` to resubscribe after the error fires.  Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Okay! I figured out the answer:  You need to `catch` the error with a catch block, return a RACSignal with the error, then `retry`, then `subscribeNext` to the success callback.  Like:

```
[[[[self.viewModel signal] catch:^RACSignal *(NSError *error) {
    // Handle the error here
    return [RACSignal error:error];
}] retry] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    // Do your success stuff
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you put the `-catch:` inside the `-flattenMap:`, then the outer signal won't error.
https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues/1218

Answer (score 0):

You need [`-[RACSignal retry]`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACSignal%2BOperations.h#L541):

```
[[[self.viewModel signal] retry] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    NSLog(@"success!");
} error:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error");
}];
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me, if I add `retry` to the signal, it's not even called the first time!  If it matters, the RACSignal in the viewModel is being sent the error like:  `[(RACSubject *)self.signal sendError:error];`